# Need help on getting customized data from table

Tags: mysql

```
+----+----------+---------+----+------+-----+------+------+
| id |   date   |  time   | s  | name | act |  l   |  p   |
+----+----------+---------+----+------+-----+------+------+
|  1 | 04-11-19 | 05:05.0 | my | A    | b   |  100 |  105 |
|  2 | 04-11-19 | 06:06.0 | my | A    | s   |  100 |   97 |
|  3 | 04-11-19 | 03:02.0 | my | B    | s   |  201 |  196 |
|  4 | 03-11-19 | 03:02.0 | my | B    | b   |  202 |  209 |
|  5 | 03-11-19 | 03:02.0 | my | E    | b   | 1202 | 1209 |
|  6 | 03-11-19 | 23:32.0 | my | E    | s   | 1188 | 1180 |
|  7 | 02-11-19 | 19:08.0 | my | C    | b   |  272 |  280 |
|  8 | 04-11-19 | 32:28.0 | my | D    | s   |  356 |  356 |
|  9 | 02-11-19 | 11:09.0 | my | B    | s   |  204 |  198 |
| 10 | 04-11-19 | 21:11.0 | my | E    | b   | 1207 | 1212 |
+----+----------+---------+----+------+-----+------+------+
```

Lets have the above mentioned MYSQL table named t. Now I want to extract below mentioned data.

1. Wish to get name, act, date, time for rows that has today's date or latest, order by date DESC and time DESC group by name WHERE s = my. Assuming today's date as 04-11-19. The result table should be as mentioned below.

```
+------+-----+----------+---------+
| name | act |   date   |  time   |
+------+-----+----------+---------+
| A    | s   | 04-11-19 | 06:06.0 |
| A    | b   | 04-11-19 | 05:05.0 |
| B    | s   | 04-11-19 | 03:02.0 |
| C    | b   | 02-11-19 | 19:08.0 |
| D    | s   | 04-11-19 | 32:28.0 |
| E    | b   | 04-11-19 | 21:11.0 |
+------+-----+----------+---------+
```

2. Wish to get name, act, date and time of recent two entries as per date and time for each group of name WHERE s = my. The result table should be as mentioned below.

```
+------+-----+----------+---------+
| name | act |   date   |  time   |
+------+-----+----------+---------+
| A    | s   | 04-11-19 | 06:06.0 |
| A    | b   | 04-11-19 | 05:05.0 |
| B    | s   | 04-11-19 | 03:02.0 |
| B    | b   | 03-11-19 | 03:02.0 |
| C    | b   | 02-11-19 | 19:08.0 |
| D    | s   | 04-11-19 | 32:28.0 |
| E    | b   | 04-11-19 | 21:11.0 |
| E    | s   | 03-11-19 | 23:32.0 |
+------+-----+----------+---------+
```

I wrote below SQL which is limiting from overall output where as I want to limit for each group of name..

SELECT name, act, date, time FROM t WHERE s = 'my' ORDER BY name ASC, date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 2

I expected below table as output for requirement 1.

```
+------+-----+----------+---------+
| name | act |   date   |  time   |
+------+-----+----------+---------+
| A    | s   | 04-11-19 | 06:06.0 |
| A    | b   | 04-11-19 | 05:05.0 |
| B    | s   | 04-11-19 | 03:02.0 |
| C    | b   | 02-11-19 | 19:08.0 |
| D    | s   | 04-11-19 | 32:28.0 |
| E    | b   | 04-11-19 | 21:11.0 |
+------+-----+----------+---------+
```

OR

expected below table as output for requirement 2.

```
+------+-----+----------+---------+
| name | act |   date   |  time   |
+------+-----+----------+---------+
| A    | s   | 04-11-19 | 06:06.0 |
| A    | b   | 04-11-19 | 05:05.0 |
| B    | s   | 04-11-19 | 03:02.0 |
| B    | b   | 03-11-19 | 03:02.0 |
| C    | b   | 02-11-19 | 19:08.0 |
| D    | s   | 04-11-19 | 32:28.0 |
| E    | b   | 04-11-19 | 21:11.0 |
| E    | s   | 03-11-19 | 23:32.0 |
+------+-----+----------+---------+
```

I've seen examples in forums about it but could not co-relate. Please help.

Comment: Your `date` and `time` fields do not appear to use a `date`, `time`, or `timestamp` field data type. That is going to make the ordering more complicated than it need be. I'd recommend combining the two fields into a single field using the `datetime`  data type.

Comment: Please help with that also if we combine the two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. Below code will do the job of 2nd question.

```
SELECT name, act, date, time FROM (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC) AS rnk FROM t) AS x WHERE rnk <= 2 AND s = 'my'
```